# PHP: Extracting important keywords from a string

Tags: php

I use the Google Images API to automatically generate thumbnails for my blog posts. I want to pick 3 or 4 important keywords from the post title and get a relevant image from Google Images. What's a good way to do this using PHP?

Comment: Unless you're making a massive amount of blog posts, why not not pick an image yourself? This also avoids the possibility of unintended copyright infringement and unwanted images.

Comment: It actually doesn't look like you can generate images with text in them with the Google Image Service. It only looks like you can do basic transformations of existing images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a good way to automatically determine which keywords are "important". However, you could put in all words with at least a certain length, or the 3 longest words, or the words of at least a certain length that occur the most in the article.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the yahho term extraction api

http://developer.yahoo.com/search/content/V1/termExtraction.html

Or maybe tagthe.net

Both are accessible from php with the likes of cURL